# typeid, how to get just type name only

Tags: c++, qt, typeid

Example code:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
        QString strTemp = typeid(this).name();
        qDebug() << strTemp;
    }
```

I want to get just the class name, in the above example I'm after just "MainWindow", what I get is:

```
    class MainWindow *
```

Of course I can write a routine that takes this string and then strips out the class and pointer parts isolating just the class name.  Is there anything that does this already?

In the absence of any standard routine, this is what I have done:

```
        QString strTemp = typeid(this).name();
        qDebug() << strTemp;
        QStringList lstParts = strTemp.split(" ");

        if ( lstParts.length > 1 ) {
            strTemp = lstParts[1];
        }
        qDebug() << strTemp;
```

The above results in only the type name.  In the end I just needed 
`__FUNCTION__` which gives the classname and method its being called from which will give:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow
```

Comment: `QString strTemp = typeid(*this).name();` ?

Comment: @songyuanyao, thank you, that got rid of the pointer "*" part, anything that will strip the "class " ?  Again, I know I can do this in code, I was looking for an already existing clean-up method.

Comment: Don't do that! It is not guaranteed you will get the name. `typeid.name()` is implimentation defined...

Comment: You have to do it manually. The string returned by `name()` is implementation defined. It seems your compiler deciding to add "class" from the beginning.

Comment: if you use boost - try boost::core::demangle

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Ayxan, Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x86)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should not rely on `std::typeid`, nor on boost or any other **C++-only-library**. None of them guarantee you will get the typename, especially with mangled types, on different compilers. Using virtual function even RTTI can influence the name of the type. Nothing prevents your compiler from renaming "MainWindow" to "CellarDoor". The only way to go so far is by using some sort of Reflection (which is not (yet) part of C++) or some preprocessor. ComicSansMS provided a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642891/1810087), where you roll your own simple reflection implementation.

However, since you are using QT you can use [QT Metaobjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) for this. It actually has a method dedicated for this exact purpose; [className](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#className).

> QMetaObject::className() returns the class name as a string at run-time, without requiring native run-time type information (RTTI) support through the C++ compiler.

Simply call `metaObject()->className()`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
    qDebug() << metaObject()->className();
}
```

[moc](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html) runs before any compiler and bakes the class name into the code. Looking into the moc generated code you will see something like:

```
static const qt_meta_stringdata_MainWindow_t qt_meta_stringdata_MainWindow = {
    {
QT_MOC_LITERAL(0, 0, 10), // "MainWindow"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(1, 11, 13), // "buttonClicked"
QT_MOC_LITERAL(2, 25, 0) // ""

    },
    "MainWindow\0buttonClicked\0"
};
```

Comment: After all that, __FUNCTION__ is better for my needs and I new about this already, I must be getting old.

Answer (score 3):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) says the following about `std::type_info::name()`:

> Returns an **implementation defined** null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. **No guarantees are given**; in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

So the fact that you got `class MainWindow` as output here under one compiler does not mean that you will get the same output under different compiler (or even the same one but newer version).

Comment: The idea is that I use a standard routine that accepts any type then strips out everything leaving just the type name.

Comment: @SPlatten And the compiler's idea is that the `class` part is part of the type name. Different compilers might have different ideas. I feel your pain, but the sad reality is that `typeid::name()` is simply not a well suited tool for your use case.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, however I can deal with the response it gives and adapt.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr` plus using some type traits, for example `remove_pointer_t` to get desired result ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

class MainWindow {
public:
    void test()
    {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << 
         boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>().pretty_name() 
          ;

        std::string s = os.str(); // easy transform to QString
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MainWindow{}.test(); // as output MainWindow
    return 0;
}
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/32E2fR)

Comment: Rather than `std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>` why not just `decltype(*this)`?

Comment: Slight problem, on my system:  boost/boost_1_61_0/boost/type_index.hpp, if I put this in I can go to the file via the IDE with "Follow Symbol Under Cursor", but when I try to build I get C1083: Cannot open include file boost/boost_1_61_0/boost/type_index.hpp

Comment: It should be enough to add `boost/boost_1_61_0/` as one of include directory paths. Then include only `boost/type_index.hpp`.

Comment: @rafix07, I tried that, when I type boost::typeindex I do not get the type_id_with_cvr as a suggestion, it only gives type_index and type_info as suggestions.

Comment: [Link for wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d3siBRzSvoDrNECv) on wandbox with boost 1.61 version code compiles fine. No prompting `type_id_with_cvr` by IDE doesn't mean that the code doesn't work. Attached link confirms that the code works under 1.61 boost.

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comment, I cannot build, although the IDE finds the header, it won't compile giving No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

`std::type_info::name()` is a bad match for this kind of task. As pointed out by [@pkrysiak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641980/577603) the return value of this function is implementation-defined, so it is not possible to strip it down to the type name as it appears in the source code in a portable way.

A better approach in this case would be to roll your own reflection mechanism, which will give you full control over the type string. Unfortunately, the language does not offer a lot of support for this at the moment, so the resulting mechanism will be a bit of a hack. For example, you could do something like this:

```
#define ENABLE_REFLECTION_TYPE_NAME(class_name)                 \
inline constexpr char const* type_name(class_name const&) {     \
    return #class_name;                                         \
}

class Foo {};

ENABLE_REFLECTION_TYPE_NAME(Foo)
ENABLE_REFLECTION_TYPE_NAME(MainWindow)

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) {
    QString strTemp = type_name(*this);
    qDebug() << strTemp;             // prints "MainWindow"

    Foo f;
    QString strTemp2 = type_name(f);
    qDebug() << strTemp2;            // prints "Foo"
}
```

Comment: I've using C and C++ since 1987 and I've never seen the syntax return # before, if it works I'm amazed I've never seen this before.

Comment: @SPlatten That's the [`# operator` of the preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace) (aka the stringification operator). It's not very useful besides shenanigans like this right here, so I'm not surprised if you haven't heard of it before.

Comment: I'm trying to create a demo using your example and failing, C2144 'const char' should be preceded by ';', C2433 'constexpr' 'inline' not permitted on data declarations, C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed and more.

Comment: @SPlatten Which compiler are you using? It works for me on [gcc, clang and MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/ZZRgRC).

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x86)

Comment: @SPlatten Then the `constexpr` is probably what's throwing him off. Try removing it from the `type_name` function signature in the macro. Unfortunately I don't have that version installed here, so I can't test it myself.

Comment: @SPlatten Make sure you're calling `type_name(*this)` and not `type_name(this)`.